# zend framework htaccess works in production server but not in xampp

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I am using this htaccess code which works in production server but not working in xampp, may i know why

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ – [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =”"
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ – [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: check if mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score -1):

On the third line you have an illegal character:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =”"
```

should be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
```

Answer (score -1):

Even after changing the non-ascii double quote to an ascii double quote, that condition should always fail because `=""`, apache will attempt to match the URI (which always begins with a slash) to the character `=`. Try changing these 2 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =”"
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.php [L]
```